# How can I download legacy software for an iPad 1?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications

YouTube has stopped working on my iPad 1, so I deleted it and tried to re-download it, but the current version requires iOS 9.0 or later. The only solution I have found involves using a computer, but I’m not allowed to and it has a lot of problems.
H
ow can I download a compatible version of YouTube on iOS 5.1.1 without a computer?

Answer (score 1):

If you bought/downloaded an app on one device and want to install it on device that has an earlier version of iOS, try these steps.

Here's how to find out if there's a compatible version of an app:

1. Open the App Store on your device.
2. Tap the Purchased tab.
3. Find the app and download it. If there's a compatible version, a message appears and you can choose Confirm to get the latest version of the app that works for your device. If there isn't a compatible version and you can't download the app, go to the app's product page and contact the developer for help.